# Broyden's method update

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, fixed-point-theorems

One version of Broyden's method for systems of nonlinear equations updates the approximation of the Jacobian matrix as follows:

$$\mathbf{J}_n ⇽ \mathbf{J}_{n-1}+\frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_n)-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_{n-1})-\mathbf{J}_{n-1}(\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1})}{||\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1}||_2^2}(\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1})^T$$

However, from the previous iteration, this solution method also uses $\mathbf{J}_{n-1}(\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1})=-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_{n-1})$ such that the above update simplifies to

$$\mathbf{J}_n ⇽ \mathbf{J}_{n-1}+\frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}_n)}{||\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1}||_2^2}(\mathbf{x}_n-\mathbf{x}_{n-1})^T$$

The above simplified version is never mentioned in books as far as I know. Is there a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no mistake. The second equation is found from considering Newton-Raphson equation:
$$-J_{n-1}(x_n-x_{n-1})=f(x_{n-1})\tag{1}$$
And secant equation:
$$J_{n}(x_n-x_{n-1})=f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})\tag{2}$$
Adding the two equations yields:
$$(J_{n}-J_{n-1})(x_n-x_{n-1})=f(x_n)\tag{3}$$
Solving for $(J_{n}-J_{n-1})$, assuming $(J_{n}-J_{n-1})(x_n-x_{n-1})^{\perp}=0$, yields:
$$(J_{n}-J_{n-1})=\frac{f(x_n)}{\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|_2^2}(x_n-x_{n-1})^T\tag{4}$$
$$(J_{n}-J_{n-1})=\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})+f(x_{n-1})}{\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|_2^2}(x_n-x_{n-1})^T\tag{5}$$
$$(J_{n}-J_{n-1})=\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})-J_{n-1}(x_n-x_{n-1})}{\|x_n-x_{n-1}\|_2^2}(x_n-x_{n-1})^T\tag{6}$$
Let, $f(x_n)-f(x_{n-1})=y$ and $x_n-x_{n-1}=s$, then:
$$J_{n}=J_{n-1}+\frac{y-J_{n-1}s}{s^Ts}(s)^T\tag{7}$$
which is the Broyden method.

Comment: What is the meaning of $x^\perp$? Any vector orthogonal to $x$?

Comment: It looks to me that (4) is better than (6) (or (7)) numerically but since (1) is used to find $x_n$, there might be no clear numerical differences between the two expressions. At least, it seems less expensive in terms of CPU.

Comment: Yes, $x^\perp$ means any vector orthogonal to x.

Comment: Yes, equations (4) and (7) are basically the same. However, equation (7) as presented is used to duduce the BFGS method.